# Unable to call function passed through to template directive by button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have moved a button which was working on the top level view into the child view two levels down, however when doing this the button now does nothing even with a debugger at the start of the function this is never hit.

What I have done so far is:

I have passed this through to the directive for the view using
`downloadReport: "&"` in both my `statsDirective` and my `StatsSummaryDirective`
I am also setting these in the view:

```
download-report="orderControllerVm.downloadReport"
download-report="extendedReachStatsController.downloadReport"
```

and am calling this in the stats summary view

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="report-order" 
          class="button primary" 
          type="button" 
          data-ng-click="extendedReachStatsSummaryController.downloadReport()">
  <?php ht('production_orders.labels.form.extended_reach_report') ?>
  </button>
</div>
```

I am not sure what the issue for this is if it is just in the way I am trying to call the function from the view, a data binding issue or from being outside of a form. I am more of a back end developer than front end so might be a simple mistake somewhere but if anyone can offer some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the editing Aleksay

Comment: Can you please add the directive code and perhaps more of the HTML code?

Comment: In the end I moved the function code into the directive and managed to get it working that way so have it working now thanks and sorry for slow reply